# HTC Desire HD vibrating constantly

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire-hd, vibration

My girlfriend plugged her phone in to charge and it started vibrating, and never stopped. The only way to stop it is to power off the phone, and take the battery out. Even if the phone is off, it still vibrates if the battery is in.

She recently installed the eBay application, and tried removing that but nothing.

Running standard HTC/Telus (Alberta, Canada) 2.2.1. Phone has not been rooted or anything else. Phone is only 3 weeks old.

I have same phone, with no problems.

How do we make it stop?

**Part 2:**

Sometimes, after removing and replacing the battery it stops. But you just have to push on the back in a spot or two and it cranks up again. Seems like a hardware problem that we can't fix. Will probably end up going back to the Telus store to see what they say, and will most likely have to warranty it.

Still open to ideas though.

**Part 3:**

We can adjust the volume up and down, and it will go all the way up to full volume, make the little 'bing' noise to let you know the volume is turned up, all while still vibrating. Going up/down, changing the ring mode in settings, changing vibration settings in keyboard and other areas have no effect.

Comment: have you tried pressing the volume up/down rocker? I find with my HTC Desire, every so often I accidentally trigger the 'vibrate' profile via the volume rocker and it keeps vibrating (I think my case might be causing the rocker to be 'stuck'?).

Though your problem does sound like a hardware issue, so this might not be the solution you're after, but if the volume rocker can stop it vibrating will be easier than turning the phone off/on.

Comment: @pyko: Good point.  Is it possible that the volume down rocker is stuck and is causing the phone to constantly try and enter the "Vibrate only" state?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a hardware issue, I'd backup anything important and take it into the shop.

Comment: I'm with @GAThrawn on this one.  Time to get some use out of that warranty.

Comment: Hardware fault = return. Would be interesting to know what the vendor/manufacturer make of it, if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody posted it as an answer, so I'm going to: It's definitely a hardware issue.  There's no way that both the simple firmware for battery charging while the phone is off has the exact same bug as the software running when the phone is on.  Mark Wain's (deleted) answer indicates that he had a similar issue that, again, is best explained by bad hardware.

Comment: A warranty fix resulted in a working phone.

Comment: @Daniel Great :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same same problem and tried to take out the battery several times and when i turned the phone on again with the battery in, and is's vibrating all the time as soon as you turn on the phone. The phone will not not event get to the starting HTC screen. it vibrates all the time until you remove the battery again.

I found that when

1. The phone is turned off
2. Set the phone in the external HTC USB charger
3. It started with the standard start HTC screeen and every thing seems to be good now. I left it in the charger for some time now

I hope this post can help any one
/Pelle

Answer (score 0):

There's a small chance that this will help you in some way, when you have this all time vibrating issue: in my case, I left a screw inside the phones case after I opened it to change the glass.

The screw somehow managed to get stuck between one contact of the vibrating motor, and the metal plate of the first case cover to remove. After reopening the phone and removing the screw the constant vibrating stopped. Phone was a HTC Wildfire and seems to work perfectly now.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, accessibility, and turn of notification reminder.